# MATLAB markup for doc-page

Tags: matlab

What resources are there for explaining how to write MATLAB comments in the correct format for display using 'doc' (that is the Help Browser).

In particular, I'm writing a class, and would like the help documentation to look like MATLAB's own. I'm focusing on the practical - such as documenting the various ways of calling a function. I haven't been able to find any documentation on what markup to use in the comments to achieve this.

(As an added bonus, I'd like the autocomplete tooltips for class functions to display something meaningful rather than `MyFunction(MyClass object...)` - but that's getting a little too specific at this stage! I'll re-ask this if it doesn't come naturally once I've got some documentation)

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840657/matlab-m-file-help-formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Matlab Help/User Guides/Desktop Tools and Developement Environment/Custromizing Helps and Demos/Providing Your Own Help and Demos

I hope this helps.

Edit:
It looks like it changed in 2012a:

Matlab Help/User Guides/Programming Fundamentals/Software Development/Create Help and Demos/Add Help for Your Program Files